# Как правильно пишется "я решал бы с этим"

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно пишется "я решал бы с этим"?

Comment: Так и пишется: "Я решал бы с этим."

Answer (score 1):

Фраза явно разговорная, ненормативная.

Если нужна литературная, лучше перестроить.

А может, "Я бы решал вопрос с этим" или  "Я бы решал этот вопрос"?

Можно и "Я бы разобрался с этим".